# Revoke user ID from revoked gpg key?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Being a total gpg noob, I fooled around generating keys on my ubuntu pc and copying those keys to the OpenKeychain phone app. I managed to successfully revoke a key from the app, so now that key sits on the servers with `revoked` tag and my daily email address forever. I do regret that.

I tried revoking the user ID from the pc having the secret key, and got error `gpg: Cannot revoke the last valid user ID.`.

Does this mean I can´t revoke an ID from a revoked key?

Comment: Why do you want to revoke an user id if the whole key is already revoked?

Comment: the key is revoked, but a key server search is showing the key with my full name and my daily email address. Perhaps not a big issue, but the whole key publishing was a silly mistake. That is why I'm looking for a way to remove the ID even if the key will live on the servers for ever.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve that. You cannot delete published ID or keys.

Comment: It namely means that a single identity can't be revoked from the key if it is the last one, and with a revoked key you cannot change any of the details stored on the public keyservers at time of revocation (that I'm aware of).